# What to do if a bounty attracted no activity?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I posted a question and got several up-votes but neither comments nor answers.  I offered a 100 pt. bounty, and still nothing.  I don't really care about losing the points but I really AM hoping for an answer!  Any thoughts?

Here is the question:
[Are there varying levels of ASCAP's "plus" awards?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118865/are-there-varying-levels-of-ascaps-plus-awards)

Comment: I don't know how others feel about this, but I've always felt that upvoting bountied questions—assuming they're good questions—helps to increase their visibility, and thus increase the likelihood of receiving worthwhile answers. I invite other users here on SE to consider this for themselves, because I'm surprised to see the question has only four votes. (Rather, +5 and -1.)

Comment: I’m not even sure if the question is on-topic. It’s at least slightly related to the business side of music, which is explicitly off topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add another, bigger, bounty. That could get more interest, and it will raise visibility of the post again.

See the [canonical post on Bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for more info

Answer (score 2):

Speaking only for myself ...

I didn't answer, because the obvious next step would have been to email them myself — knowing your attempt had already received no response — and then follow up with a potentially time-consuming call or series of calls. However, I decided to leave it alone, since 1) the website description seems to make clear that they don't publicize information about the award amounts (simply by the absence of any mention), and 2) the phone call(s) would be something you could do yourself.

It's possible I would have been motivated to do the work by a larger bounty.

Comment: I guess I was hoping some bigger-name composer would brag about their larger award and answer my question.….